# Pinboard website (i.e., non-Emacs) bookmark editing in Emacs

Tags: bookmarks, web-browser

I recently switched over to `pinboard.in` for organizing website bookmarks. I'm looking for a way to organize my bookmarks in Emacs. I've installed the `pinboard-api` package but I can't seem to find any of the pinboard commands in the helm autocomplete menu.

I've also looked at using the `pinboard-list.el` package that's hosted on github. But it doesn't seem to be maintained. Perhaps I'm manually loading the package wrong. I'm loading it with the following in the user-config section of my `~/.emacs` file. I know it's kind of crude but it should get the job done:

```
(load-file "~/elisp/pinboard-list.el" )
```

Does anyone have experience with these packages? Or is there a different package you'd recommend more? Or some documentation that shows how to load the package and set up good keybindings for the functions?

I'm really just looking to bulk-edit website bookmarks and add multiple tags.

Comment: I've also tried loading the pinboard-api package with (require pinboard-api)

I apologize if any of this is foolish. I've just switched over from using vim to spacemacs/evil emacs and I don't quite understand how packages are loaded.

Comment: note: I'm using spacemacs with version 24.5.1 of emacs. I'm beginning to think my issue with the packages is how spacemacs controls the layers

Comment: Maybe this will help you? https://github.com/joddie/pinboard-list.el.

Answer (score 1):

This answer responds to your general question, "*I'm really just looking to bulk-edit website bookmarks and add multiple tags.*" It does not help with the part of your question that is Pinboard-specific.

If you use the Emacs web browser EWW then you can bookmark web pages *within Emacs*.

These "bookmarks" are not the standard [Emacs bookmarks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bookmarks.html), however.

If you use also use [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) (with EWW) then you can bookmark web pages using standard Emacs bookmarks.

(Well, the bookmarks are specific to Bookmark+ - you need Bookmark+ to set and jump to them, but they are in your standard Emacs bookmarks file and they use the format of standard Emacs bookmarks, which is not the case for the "bookmarks" you get with only EWW.)

And with Bookmark+ you can **tag** any bookmark with any number of arbitrary tags. And you can search for (i.e., filter) bookmarks according to their tags and combinations of tags, in several ways.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that in the future. My current issue is the 7000 bookmarks I currently have tagged in pinboard.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that might be the case. ;-) If they are in an ordinary, plain-text form, or if you can export them to such a form, then you can perhaps convert them to be usable by EWW. Dunno.